# COM addin accesing another COM addin in oulook

Tags: vb.net, plugins, com, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a COM plugin which is an app bought from a company, it provides a few menu bars in outlook and I want to be able to automate some button clicks and processes with the bought COM plugin by making my own COM plugin that will access the other.

I'm using C# or VB in the outlook plugin, not sure, eitherway I need to know is it possible to have my plugin control the other, e.g. a a typical scenario would be for my plugin to execute the button click on the purchased plugin enter some text and then click another button eg. to save a form

any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks